# Can't modify boostrap theme properly

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

So I added a custom .css file from a theme I found on the internet, which overrides some boostrap properties, and it seems to work on some ocassions, but for example, if I change the primary color in the :root{} part of the styles.css, it doesn't seem to change anything. Futhermore, how should I know keep using the same bootstrap syntax in my renders?

**root of styles.css**

```
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #1abc9c;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #1abc9c;
    --secondary: #2c3e50;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #ffc107;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: "Lato", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
        "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif,
        "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas,
        "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

**bootstrap syntax**

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change bootstrap theme with like rgb codes, but you must use the preset that they offer to you

Comment: What about custom variable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap includes its core CSS classes, but also has a "reboot" style sheet that changes core HTML5 element styles. This includes changes to the html and body elements that control text-based, inherited properties. They call these styles a "reboot", but its just a simpler version of a "reset" element sheet. That sheet simply picks a subset of HTML5 elements and "resets" a few of their style properties before they layer over their custom classes. We have done these types of HTML element resets for years, but using a more robust set for old and new browsers. Ive found Bootstrap's more immature reset version causes confusion and unpredictability, changing how the default UA browser elements look prior to adding Bootstrap style classes, which are predictable.

To address this I have built a Bootstrap "cleaner" style sheet that strips those styles out while allowing you to use their regular classes. The result is you have more control over text-based inheritance, styles set on the html and body elements, and their overall box model changes which are not always supported in older agents. I wont post that sheet here unless someone asks.

But here is one small sample of that **Bootstrap Cleaner Style Sheet** that would remove Bootstrap's default fonts and colors for you without affecting the rest of the custom classes you use in Bootstrap. You could then apply your own body fonts and colors as I do but still use Bootstrap's style classes. Note this works in IE and non-IE browsers by using fallback properties then "all:revert" for newer browsers who can reset property values back to the default browser style sheet:

```
html body {
    display: block;
    margin: initial;
    zoom: 1;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: initial;
    padding: initial;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    color: initial;
    text-align: initial;
    background-color: initial;
    all: revert;
}
```